# Мониторинг серверов Minecraft

Tags: php

Реализую сайт, использующий в своей работе различные данные мониторинга *Minecraft-серверов*. Вывод онлайн, максимального количества игроков, используемых плагинов, и прочего добра.

Есть сайты с готовыми *API*, возвращающие *json-массив* с данными, к примеру.
Боюсь, что подобные сайты-посредники отвалятся через некоторое время.

Какой способ лучше?

Какие способы еще есть?

Comment: [Вот это](http://mcjsonapi.com/) подойдет?

Answer (score 1):

Минимальное гугляние натолкнуа на такую вот библиотеку https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал GameQ для мониторинга CS серверов. Работало неплохо. В списке поддерживаемых протоколов есть и Minecraft. https://github.com/Austinb/GameQ

Comment: Документация к протоколу для Minecraft http://austinb.github.io/GameQ/api/class-GameQ.Protocols.Minecraft.html